# How to get an asynchronous ouput in a Python cmd shell?

Tags: python, asynchronous, cmd

I use the [cmd](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html) module to create an interactive shell.

The workflow is a usual one: enter command, print result. But the result will be processed asynchronously,then stacked in a queue. I then need some way to get it back into my shell to display it.

How can I push data from ouside my shell into my shell and print it ? Should I use a pipe or a signal ? I have no clue.

I mainly need something that works underlinux but cross platform is always a nice to have.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only for display purposes, you can just `print` the result to `c.stdout` (`c` is `cmd.Cmd` object). Will that work for you?

Comment: The data should be pushed from an external process so it won't have access to the cms reference.